# Hibernate разница между Session и EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Хотелось бы понять в чем разница между этими двумя объектами. Из прочитанного в интернете я понял, что EntityManager это объект, полностью удовлетворяющий спецификации JPA, и что если нужно будет перейти на какой-либо другой фреймворк то при использовании EntityManager это можно будет с легкостью сделать. В случае с Session этот вариант не возможен так как он не является точной реализацией JPA. 
Вопрос в том какие преимущества у Session перед EntityManager, ради чего стоит отказываться от переносимости при его использовании?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hibernate появился в далеком 2001 году, тогда JPA еще не было. JPA появилось во многом стараниями Hibernate и только в 2006 году.

К этому времени у Hibernate был большой наработанный функционал, а в для первой версии JPA удалось согласовать (с другими фирмами-разработчиками аналогичных продуктов) только часть этого объема функционала. Поэтому, разработчики Hibernate сознательно (чтобы не было путаницы) пошли на то, чтобы в Hibernate имелось два пути работы - старый путь - нативный Hibernate (через интерфейс `Session`) и новый путь JPA (через интерфейс `EntityManager`). Интерфейсы разные, методы как правило имеют одинаковые названия. Различия есть и в других элементах - например, Hibernate конфигурируется файлом `hibernate.cfg.xml`, основанном на DTD, а JPA - `persistence.xml`, основанном на XSD, кроме того, во многих областях приняты различные правила по умолчанию. При этом, функциональность нативного Hibernate значительно больше, чем у JPA.

И вообще, Hibernate не делал две различные реализации - одну для `Session`, а другую для `EntityManager`. Реализация `EntityManager` является оберткой (wrap) реализации `Session`. Класс `SessionImpl` реализует интерфейс `Session`, а `Session` расширяет интерфейс `EntityManager`.

Если Вы выбираете путь JPA, то всегда имеете возможность быстро перейти, на другие реализации JPA - EclipseLink, OpenJPA, DataNucleus (и узнаете насколько они совместимы). Такая возможность может показаться единственным преимущество `EntityManager` перед `Session`, при существенно меньшем объеме функциональности.

При желании, можно работая с `EntityManager` дотянуться через unwrap до интерфейса `Session` и воспользоваться его функционалом (ведь реализация у этих интерфейсов единая), но тогда при переходе на другие реализации такие места нужно будет переписывать особо. Такая техника, рекомендуется разработчиками Hibernate, хотя на мой взгляд это немного из цирка.  Но главное, что разработчики Hibernate подают его (Hibernate) во-первых как реализацию JPA и только во-вторых вспоминают о дополнительных возможностях `Session`.

В путевых картах 6 и 7 версии Hibernate, фактически говорится о том, что JPA будет вбирать в себя самое лучшее, а остальное в Hibernate будет как бы deprecated. В последних версиях пятого Hibernate, например, у `Session` стал deprecated `createCriteria` и эта часть перенесена в JPA.

Comment: "При этом, функциональность нативного HIBERNATE значительно больше, чем у JPA", можете перечислить основные преимущества в функциональности?

Comment: Мы можем говорить, о том, что JPA имеет необходимый функционал для обеспечения персистности, а Session - расширенный. Скажем Session имеет возможность создания HIBERNATE view - это может оказаться очень удобным. Вы можете сравнить интерфейсы Session и EntitySession и увидеть, что в нем гораздо больше функциональности. Дать перечень оновных преимуществ я, извините, не готов.

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от того, насколько сильно проект привязан к Hibernate. Если проект не использует непосредственно API Hibernate или, по крайней мере, может не использовать эти API, то можно использовать `EntityManager` и JPA.

С одной стороны это даёт возможность в процессе разработки заменить Hibernate на другую реализацию JPA, но с другой - а насколько вероятно возникновение ситуации, когда понадобится замена Hibernate? По-моему в первую очередь надо ориентироваться на удобство использования и предпочтения личные и/или команды.

Если в архитектуре проекта работа с БД выделена в отдельную абстракцию, то замена фреймворка, используемого для работы с БД, повлечёт за собой минимум изменений.

Comment: вопрос был немного в другом, есть ли у session какие то серьезные преимущества перед EntityManager, потому что не понятно, почему бы всегда не использовать EntityManager, раз уж он реализован по стандарту и эти два объекта делают вроде бы одно и тоже

Comment: Кроме совместимости с другими реализациями JPA преимуществ нет. Решение, что использовать: JPA или Hibernate, как правило, не связано с различиями в функциональности, т.к. они минимальны и несущественны.