# В чем отличия между Datasouce, SessionFactory, Entity manager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю

**DataSource**  - это объект, который позволяет для JDBC Template получать соединения с БД. Точнее он содержит пул соединений, а jdbcTemplate берет из пула

**SessionFactory** - это объект Hibernate, который предоставляет сессии - по факту те же соединения с БД.

Поскольку они оба создаются примерно одинаково - указывается путь до БД, логин, пароль
и поскольку они оба предоставляют соединения с БД, делаю вывод что это по факту одинаковые объекты, просто 1 нужен для работы с jdbcTemplate , другой для Hibernate

И **EntityManager**  - это тоже самое что SessionFactory, только EntityManager  подходит под JPA и он будет работать хоть с Hibernate, хоть с другой реализацией JPA (видимо SessonFactory чет все таки еще делает, раз его в Hibernate создали)

Comment: Какой конкретный вопрос? У тебя абсолютно неверное представление об классах.

Comment: Конкретный вопрос в заголовке - я не понимаю отличий между этими 3-мя классами. У меня есть примеры по видео с ютуба где в одном случае мы создаем HikariDataSource и он используется для соединений. В другом SessionFactory используется для соединений. В 3-ем EntityManager .

Comment: Наверно тебе надо почитать и хорошенько изучить [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/965018/224103